# Set scroll position to bottom in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a div in which I am calling an api after certain height limit say if my `scrollTop` of that element equals 0 then it calls api to fetch certain amount of data .

```
// OnScroll Chat Handler

this.refs.customerChatScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {

    let chatScroll = this.refs.customerChatScroll.scrollTop ;

        if ( chatScroll === 0 ){

            this.loadMoreChat();

        }
});
```

So how to I make my scroller automatically align at bottom in chat area after every api call ?

This is what I am using it to align at end of chat area but wont be able to properly align after every api call

```
scrollToBottom = () => {

    this.messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({ block: "end"});

}

componentDidUpdate() {

    if(this.props.scrollDown){

        this.scrollToBottom();

    }

}

render() {

    return(

        <div 
            className="customerChatHistory" 
            ref={(el) => { this.messagesEnd = el }}>
            { this.props.children }            
        </div>
    )

}
```